# how can I pass a var using a link that toggles open a modal

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Basically I'd like to do this:

```
a href=msgtest.php?the_id=$sender_id
```

but using this:

```
a href=''data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal30'
```

How can I pass data using the link that toggles the modal

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info" href="msgtest.php?<?php the_id=$sender_id ?>" data-target="#myModal">Click me !</a>



  <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
<?php
     echo  $_GET["the_id"] 

?>
 </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div> <!-- /.modal -->
```